# Nodes vs Members in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nodes, member

I get confused by terms in MongoDB documentation. In documentation it is mixed: sometimes a MongoDB instance is named **node** sometimes **member**.

See https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-states/ it says

> ... each **member** of a replica set has a state that reflects...

and see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-primary/ it says

> In some circumstances, two **nodes** in a replica set may transiently
>   believe that they are the primary, but at most, one of them will be
>   able to complete writes with { w: "majority" } write concern. The **node**
>   that can complete { w: "majority" } writes is the current primary, and
>   the other **node** is a former primary that has not yet recognized its
>   demotion, typically due to a network partition

Which one is describing what?

Why documentation uses **node** and **member** not only one of them?

Is there any difference?

Comment: This is definitely vague language, might want to open a JIRA to standardise this since they are exactly the same. A member is a node

Comment: Ty. Which one should we prefer in context of MongoDB then? :)

Comment: I would personally got for member

Comment: JIRA opened. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-6940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Member** and **Node** are interchangeable in MongoDB context. Both are valid and legal. Use whatever you like.